# splitting a number into several pats depending on the length of the number

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame made of one column called Numbers and a single value of a very long number:

Numbers
238465850...

Now I want to create another data frame of one column also but having multiple values made from dividing the original number into equal parts depending on its integers length.
So, suppose the original number 238465850... is made of 1 million integers. i want to break this number into 1000000/100 numbers. The new data frame should have one column of 10000 values, like this:

Numbers
238465850...
347586903...
638456995...
.
.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toy example where you actually want to divide in `n_parts=`2 and not by 100:

```
>>> big_number = 15615384984136871611246544399657
>>> big_number = str(big_number)
>>> n_parts= 2
>>> n_digits = len(big_number) // n_parts
>>> [int(big_number[i:i+n_digits]) for i in range(0, len(big_number), n_digits)]
[1561538498413687, 1611246544399657]
```

Put that into a function:

```
>>> def make_parts(big_number: int, n_parts: int):
>>>     big_number = str(big_number)
>>>     n_digits = len(big_number) // n_parts
>>>     return [int(big_number[i:i+n_digits]) for i in range(0, len(big_number), n_digits)]
```

Now supposing your input dataframe was called `df` and only had one value, you can create the new one `df2` with the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(make_parts(df.iloc[0]["Numbers"], n_parts=100), columns=["Numbers"])
```

All in all (for the toy example, pay attention to `n_parts` parameter):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([15615384984136871611246544399657], columns=["Numbers"])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(make_parts(df.iloc[0]["Numbers"], n_parts=2), columns=["Numbers"])
>>> print(df2)

            Numbers
0  1561538498413687
1  1611246544399657
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, when I run the program , i am getting the following error code: "OverflowError: int too large to convert to float". What could the problem be?

Comment: I'm afraid your number is too large for your available computer memory. Not sure why it's casted to float somewhere though, do you explicitly call `float()` somewhere? Do you know for what code line exactly this error pops up?

Comment: Well, when i run the function directly things go well, however, when i try to get the data frame command, i get the error message. not sure why. Anyway, the function is enough for me. Thanks.